# Getting some errors when trying to recorde a video using CameraX VideoCapture API

Tags: video-capture, android-camerax

i am implementing an android application and i am trying to record a video using CameraX VideoCapture Api but i am getting some errors and i would like to know to figure them out . Here is the video recording code :

```
    private fun recordVideo() {
        binding.buttonCapture.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_stop_24)

        val currentRecording = recording
        if (currentRecording != null) {
            // A recording is already in progress, stop it
            currentRecording.stop()
            recording = null
            binding.buttonCapture.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_camera_24)
            return
        }

        val name: String = SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS",
            Locale.getDefault()
        ).format(System.currentTimeMillis())
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "Movies/CameraX-Recorder")
        }

        val options = MediaStoreOutputOptions.Builder(requireContext().contentResolver, EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
            .setContentValues(contentValues)
            .build()

        recording = videoCapture?.output?.prepareRecording(requireContext(), options)
            ?.start(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext())) { videoRecordEvent ->
                // Handle different recording events
                when (videoRecordEvent) {
                    is VideoRecordEvent.Start -> {
                        // Handle the start of a new active recording
                        binding.buttonCapture.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_stop_24)
                    }
                    is VideoRecordEvent.Pause -> {
                        // Handle the case where the active recording is paused
                    }
                    is VideoRecordEvent.Resume -> {
                        // Handle the case where the active recording is resumed
                    }
                    is VideoRecordEvent.Finalize -> {
                        val finalizeEvent = videoRecordEvent as VideoRecordEvent.Finalize
                        // Handle the finalize event for the active recording, checking Finalize.getError()
                        val error = finalizeEvent.error
                        if (error != VideoRecordEvent.Finalize.ERROR_NONE) {
                            // Handle error during recording finalization
                            Toast.makeText(
                                requireContext(),
                                "There was an error during video finalization: ${videoRecordEvent.error}",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                requireContext(),
                                "The video has been successfully recorded",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }
                        binding.buttonCapture.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_camera_24)
                    }
                }
                // All events, including VideoRecordEvent.Status, contain RecordingStats.
                // This can be used to update the UI or track the recording duration.
                val recordingStats = videoRecordEvent.recordingStats
            }
    }
```

here are errors , i am getting :

> Exception while executing runnable androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$1@3592bcb
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Albums cannot be directly modified
> at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:221)
> at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:189)
> at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:549)
> at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:2151)
> at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:2113)
> at androidx.camera.video.Recorder$RecordingRecord.lambda$initializeRecording$1(Recorder.java:2847)
> at androidx.camera.video.Recorder$RecordingRecord$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.get(Unknown Source:4)
> at androidx.camera.video.Recorder$RecordingRecord.performOneTimeMediaMuxerCreation(Recorder.java:3070)
> at androidx.camera.video.Recorder.setupAndStartMediaMuxer(Recorder.java:1464)
> at androidx.camera.video.Recorder$4.onEncodedData(Recorder.java:1666)
> at androidx.camera.video.internal.encoder.EncoderImpl$MediaCodecCallback.lambda$sendEncodedData$3(EncoderImpl.java:1227)
> at androidx.camera.video.internal.encoder.EncoderImpl$MediaCodecCallback$$ExternalSyntheticLambda10.run(Unknown Source:4)
> at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$1.run(SequentialExecutor.java:111)
> at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.workOnQueue(SequentialExecutor.java:231)
> at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.run(SequentialExecutor.java:173)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
> 2023-06-08 09:52:05.099 11359-11577 Recorder                                                   E  FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraX-camerax_io_0
> Process: com.ticanalyse.lagfo_kotlin, PID: 11359
> java.lang.AssertionError: One-time media muxer creation has already occurred for recording RecordingRecord{getOutputOptions=MediaStoreOutputOptions{fileSizeLimit=0, durationLimitMillis=0, location=null, contentResolver=android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver@2a50ef2, collectionUri=content://media/external/audio/albums, contentValues=_display_name=2023-06-08-09-52-04-760 mime_type=video/mp4 relative_path=Movies/CameraX-Recorder}, getCallbackExecutor=android.os.HandlerExecutor@c014943, getEventListener=com.ticanalyse.lagfo_kotlin.VideoRecorder$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2@db0cbc0, hasAudioEnabled=false, isPersistent=false, getRecordingId=1}
> at androidx.camera.video.Recorder$RecordingRecord.performOneTimeMediaMuxerCreation(Recorder.java:3067)
> at androidx.camera.video.Recorder.setupAndStartMediaMuxer(Recorder.java:1464)
> at androidx.camera.video.Recorder$4.onEncodedData(Recorder.java:1666)
> at androidx.camera.video.internal.encoder.EncoderImpl$MediaCodecCallback.lambda$sendEncodedData$3(EncoderImpl.java:1227)
> at androidx.camera.video.internal.encoder.EncoderImpl$MediaCodecCallback$$ExternalSyntheticLambda10.run(Unknown Source:4)
> at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$1.run(SequentialExecutor.java:111)
> at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.workOnQueue(SequentialExecutor.java:231)
> at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.run(SequentialExecutor.java:173)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

Answer (score 0):

Seems a permission issue. Does your app have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`/`requestLegacyExternalStorage` permission?

Comment: Yes it does .  I have added this permission

Answer (score 0):

From the log,

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Albums cannot be directly modified`

and `collectionUri=content://media/external/audio/albums`

Look like you should use `MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` instead of `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`